# Triggering 3G icon

Tags: android

I'm working on a development Android smartphone running on Android GB. I see that the 3G icon comes up all of a sudden even when there is no data connection.

The use case to reproduce the issue is:
1) Delete all the APNs from the list of APNs in the settings app. Now data connectivity goes OFF and 3G icon disappears.
2) Now restart the phone. 3G icon is visible even though there are no APNs in the APN list, and data connectivity is OFF.

Who triggers the visibility of the 3G icon? It has to be some part in Telephony Framework. I'm not able to figure out who triggers the ON/OFF of this icon in the notification bar.

Comment: Yes, it's triggered by underlying telephony stuff..., you don't have any control over it from the SDK level, instead, you'd probably want to look in the actual Android implementation, is this what you're modifying?

Comment: Yes, I have complete access to Android Framework and RIL and have the freedom to modify them